# Design for JWT token

Tags: web-services, security, hash, cryptography, jwt

I've seen people implementing invalidatable JWT token by combining the user's password, last logout time, and a shared secret in some way and use it as that user's JWT secret. That way, changing the password or logging out effectively invalidates all existing tokens.

My questions are

1. Is this a reasonable/good design?
2. If yes, *how* should I combine the three values into the new secret to make sure nothing bad happens (I'm completely new to cryptography)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be storing passwords in [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) has format - you shouldn't use the password itself as any type of key held in memory.

If you swap using the password for the bcrypt hash then this is OK, or even better you could simply store and use the date/time of the last password change. If you wish to save storage requirements, you could have a "last change date" that is updated on logout *or* on password change.

Note that this sort of setup means you cannot support multiple sessions per account as if one session is logged out, all sessions under that user account will also.

Overall this seems a good way to invalidate tokens server-side, since the secret simply ends up part of the keyed hash in the [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

You could SHA-224 the last_update_date with the actual secret to get the key to use.

e.g.

```
secret = sha-224(last_update_time || ":" || static_secret)
```

However, as you are going to be checking with the database on *every* request, this mostly defeats all the advantages of JTWs - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35728065/413180).

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer sha-224 over say sha-512?

Comment: If you're using HS256 in the JWT, then you only need the secret to be 128 bits. See [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/96176/8340).